# How to get date & time of exceptions in Python errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

Sometimes it would be happened that my services (which started manually in `tmux` or `screen`) will be stop by getting an unknown or other kinds of exceptions that I didn't handle them. In my case date & time of exceptions event is so important.

So how to get date & time of exceptions in Python errors? Like running a service in `tmux` or `screen` and wait to see the results which it will print.

Comment: Do you need to store it some where? like log file?

Comment: Write the exception together with a timestamp to a logfile.

Comment: @anonymous no, actually It will be run by command line and there is no log file.

Comment: @Mortezaipo look into `sys.excepthook`, you can write your own function to handle uncaught exceptions.

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo Thank you so much! It works great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this issue, we can try to use [sys.excepthook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) like so:

```
import sys
import traceback
import datetime

def err(type, value, tb):
    print("Exception date time: {}".format(datetime.datetime.now()))
    print(traceback.print_tb(tb))

sys.excepthook = err
```